# .NET Core MVC - ModelBinder throws Error?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

took me quite long to find this and I am still not sure what is happening.

View:

```html
@model MyFileViewModel

<div>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyFile.Name)       
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyFile.Name)
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyFile.Extension)       
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyFile.Extension)
    
    <form  method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.MyFile.Id" type="hidden" />
    <select asp-for="@Model.MyFile.State" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyState>()"> </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" asp-action="SaveEdit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveEdit(MyFileViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

Model:

```cs
class MyFileViewModel {
    public MyFile MyFile {get; set;}
    //....
}

class MyFile{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public MyState State {get; set;}
    public string Extension {get; set;}
    public string GetExtensionWithoutPoint
    {
        get { return Extension.Substring(1); }
    }
}
```

This is basically my setup and where the Error is thrown.
When I click on "Edit" then I will get an `System.NullReferenceException` in `GetExtensionWithoutPoint`.

Why?

The post Method itself is never opened, this happens in the ModelBinder. The Error is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Information: Entity Framework Core........with options: None MyFile.Extension.**get** returned null.

Or longer:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter<TDeclaringType,
TValue>(Func<TDeclaringType, TValue> getter, object target)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy+Enumerator+<>c__DisplayClass13_1.<MoveNext>b__1()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationEntry.get_Model()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy
strategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy
defaultStrategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitImplementation(ref
ModelMetadata metadata, ref string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata
metadata, string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy
strategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy
defaultStrategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitImplementation(ref
ModelMetadata metadata, ref string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata
metadata, string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Validate(ModelMetadata
metadata, string key, object model, bool alwaysValidateAtTopLevel,
object container)
```

Why is this Property even called?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this Property even called?

Because in your code, you use `asp-for="@Model.MyFile.xxx"`, it will call MyFile, then call MyFile.Extension.

If you want `return Extension.Substring(1);`

How about give an value to Extension  like:

```
public string Extension { get; set; } = "hello";
```

> The post Method itself is never opened, this happens in the
> ModelBinder.

Model binding goes through some steps, then calls the SaveEdit method.
You can read [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#example) to more.

Comment: I know that it goes through the Variables, but why would it call an Property? And no, I don´t need the "Extension" here.

Comment: @SuperNev  `return Extension.Substring(1);`  need the  Extension not null.

Comment: @SuperNev You can set a breakpoint at MyFile class, then when you click the edit button , it will excute the get of every properties. The model binding system Retrieves data from various sources such as route data, form fields,`@Model.MyFile`  call the MyFile class.  When it excute the get of `return Extension.Substring(1); `, it will find the Extension is null. But `.Substring(1)` need Extension not null. The substring() method extracts characters, between two indices (positions), from a string, and returns the substring.  It call an Property: Extension.